# Does CVE-2014-0195 affect HTTPS?

Tags: tls, openssl

Does [CVE-2014-0195](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-0195) (openSSL) affect HTTPS or only VPN tunnels?

Reference: https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/DSA-2950-1, https://isc.sans.edu/

Answer (score 2):

"All versions of OpenSSL are vulnerable to CVE-2014-0195, but this vulnerability only affects DTLS clients or servers (look for SSL VPNs... not so much HTTPS)." is already right in the posting you linked to.  If it is using DTLS, then it could be impacted potentially, but HTTPS generally doesn't.

Comment: "not so much HTTPS" is not very precise. I need more than that.

Comment: He was describing what generally uses DTLS.  That's the key part.  DTLS is the vulnerable component.  If you are using it, then vulnerable, if not, then you aren't.

Comment: DTLS - so things like LDAP, SNMP, WebRTS, VOIP, DTLS VPN, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This affects only DTLS(TLS over datagram). Hence, HTTPS and VPN tunnels which use TCP/IP would not be affected.